# Check Content Type in Paragraph Preprocess

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I've written a paragraph preprocess function that is working perfectly. The only issue is that I need it to only work when that paragraph is embedded in a certain content type.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_paragraph__paragraph_type(&$variables) {
   // Do things here if content type == 'specified_type'
}
```

I'm unsure of how to check the content type, though. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct way of getting the entity data referencing to your paragraph is to use Paragraph's entity API.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_paragraph().
 *
 * @param array $variables
 *   An associative array containing:
 *   - elements: An array of elements to display in view mode.
 *   - paragraph: The paragraph object.
 *   - view_mode: View mode; e.g., 'full', 'teaser'...
 */

function mytheme_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {
  /** @var \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph $paragraph */
  $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];
  // Get the parent bundle.
  $parentBundle = $paragraph->getParentEntity()->bundle();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is another post with either the same or similar answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116325/how-to-programmatically-get-content-type-name-in-drupal-8

The poster Jose points out you can use

$node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');

to get the content type.

Comment: That question is not about the Paragraph module and the entity it implements. It is also probable the code shown there needs to be updated for the latest Drupal versions.